# Sapphire RX 550, differences in models and consequences on hashrate

Tags: mining, gpu-mining, hashrate, cryptonight

I'm new to mining, and I wanted to use Sapphire RX 550 GPUs to build a CryptoNight rig after reading a couple posts on the Internet about them, for instance:

- [How To Get 470 h/s On CryptoNote Algorithm With RX 550 2GB](https://www.xmrstak.com/2018/02/09/get-470-h-s-cryptonote-algorithm-rx-550-2gb/)
- [Kudos to the RX 550](https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroMining/comments/6thht8/kudos_to_the_rx_550/)

All the posts seem to refer to the 11268-03 version of [this GPU](http://www.sapphiretech.com/productdetial.asp?pid=EBB5FCE8-FC92-4603-8D05-8BC8A2AF6E64&lang=eng#11268-16), but it is hard to find where I live. 11268-16 is the other version of this card, with lower performance.

My question is: is there a way I can reasonably determine the difference in hashrate between the models, given their specification?
The main differences are the GPU clock speed (1206 MHz vs 1071 Mhz) and the RAM speed (7000 MHz vs 6000 Mhz).
Can I expect a linear decrease in hashrate of roughly 15% due to these values, or are there other factors to take into account?